# bazel connect find_package from cmake

Tags: cmake, bazel, find-package

I'm trying to use bazel's cmake from rules_foreign_cc to build a library called fcl. That package has, in it's CMakeLists.txt, a `find_package(ccd QUIET)` statement. It wants to find the `ccd` (or `libccd`) package. I build that package as well, but just using cc_library. How can I get the `find_package` statement to find the package that I build?

So

```
cc_library(
    name = "libccd",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    include_prefix = "libccd/src",
    hdrs = [stuff],
    srcs = [stuff],
}

cmake(
    name = "fcl",
    cache_entries = {
        ?maybe this?
    },
    env_vars = {
        ?maybe this?
    },
    lib_source = "@fcl//:all",
    deps = [
        ":libccd",
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I build that package as well, **but just using cc_library**. How can I get the find_package statement to find the package that I build?

You have shot yourself in the foot, here.

`fcl`'s `find_package` statement is going to search for a file called `ccd-config.cmake`, using the search procedure documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure

If you had that file, I would suggest setting the cache variable `ccd_ROOT` to whichever local prefix into which you have installed `ccd`. But since you went through Bazel, that file will not exist.

You therefore have three options:

1. Use CMake to build `ccd` to get it to generate the correct package configuration files.
2. Write your own `Findccd.cmake` find module, setting the cache variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in `fcl`'s build to whichever directory in your source tree contains it. This find module will have to locate the Bazel-produced artifacts and replicate upstream `ccd`'s interface, including variable and target naming.
3. Write a Bazel build for `fcl`.

Writing find modules is *very* annoying, especially when the upstream has put in the effort to create CMake package configuration files. There is documentation for doing so here, though: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#a-sample-find-module

Comment: "You have shot yourself in the foot, here." Yeah, sigh. Maybe starting with the choice of bazel at all. Second trying to use cmake with bazel.

Comment: Maybe more color: the reason I did cc_library for ccd is because that library's existing cmake system writes the headers and libraries into /usr/wherever. Which is exactly what I don't want - I want to write the .so or .a and *.h into the bazel sandbox (or whatever it's called). I didn't want to do the same thing for fcl, because it's so complex. So I thought I'd try to find a way to feed the ccd build artifacts into cmake for fcl. But it's obv a big foot-gun...

Comment: @Colin - you can install `ccd` wherever you want by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to any directory. That directory can then be the value of `ccd_ROOT` in `fcl`'s build. You don't have to install them on top of each other.

Comment: Ah, any ideas for how to point that into bazel's sandbox? Something like `cache_entries = {"CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX"="@libccd"}` (if I use bazel's cmake to build ccd as well)? I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: @Colin - I don't really use Bazel, but it _would_ be a cache entry in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to bazelize fcl. Not sure, but maybe this has been done already [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/e59b7fc18dbe80b827d07e4a3283a0c87eda7021/tools/workspace/fcl). I bazelized a few CMake projects in the past and it always worked well (e.g. [openexr](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr), [oneTBB](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB), [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/tree/master/support/bazel))